# Get result out of array map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm having problems getting the result for 'newestLine' out of the array map function. 
The first `console.log` gives the correct result the second two gives undefined.

```
         var currentArr = [+1+SN5M+K114987A+ZO1075892+ICRR+191009+000000+GU345HB+EC2419+1 ITEMS, +1+SN5M+K114987A+ZO1075892+I139+191009+151600+COVENTRY DEPOT+EC2419+1 ITEMS, +1+SN5M+K114987A+ZO1075892+ISCN+191009+151600+GU345HB+EC2419+1 ITEMS]

            currentArr.map(function(obj) {     
            if (obj.split('+')[7] > maxid) {
                maxid = obj.split('+')[7]; 
                var newestLine = obj;
                console.log(newestLine);
                return newestLine;
            }
            console.log(newestLine);
            return newestLine;
        });
        console.log(newestLine);
```

Comment: Can you please supply some test data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: I would suggest reading another js tutorial. You appear to be throwing completely unrelated things at problems (async/await), in a trial-and-error way. That's not a time efficient way to code, or learn how to.

Comment: Basically, you've declared `newestLine` inside an `if` block inside a function and are trying to get its value outside of both. That's not how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second two `newestLine` gives undefined because of the variable `newestLine` out of their scope.

Do like this

```js
var newestLine;
currentArr.map(function(obj) {     
            if (obj.split('+')[7] > maxid) {
                maxid = obj.split('+')[7]; 
                newestLine = obj;
                console.log(newestLine);
                return newestLine;
            }
            console.log(newestLine);
            return newestLine;
        });
        console.log(newestLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use the variable **newestLine** in the local scope within the function you pass to the map function.Change the scope of the variable by declaring it before the function and use it with in the function to get the expected result

```
var currentArr = [+1+SN5M+K114987A+ZO1075892+ICRR+191009+000000+GU345HB+EC2419+1 ITEMS, +1+SN5M+K114987A+ZO1075892+I139+191009+151600+COVENTRY DEPOT+EC2419+1 ITEMS, +1+SN5M+K114987A+ZO1075892+ISCN+191009+151600+GU345HB+EC2419+1 ITEMS]
 var newestLine;
            currentArr.map(function(obj) {     
            if (obj.split('+')[7] > maxid) {
                maxid = obj.split('+')[7]; 
                 newestLine = obj;
                console.log(newestLine);
                return newestLine;
            }
            console.log(newestLine);
            return newestLine;
        });
        console.log(newestLine);
```